# Show name of month according to a number in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I wonder if there is a way to show the content of a cell container an integer (1-12) as the name of the month (Jan-Dec). If I do it this way:

```
With Cells("A1")
    .NumberFormatLocal = "MMM"
    .Value = 5
End With
```

Excel reads the value 5 as the date 5 Jan 1900 as thus returns Jan, while what I want is May.

The thing is I do not want to write a date in cell A1 but only a single integer. When cell A1 is copied by value to another cell or when read, I hope that the value copied/read is 5, not 42129 as if it is 5 May 2015. So conversion is not what I want.

Is there any custom code of formatting and other technique that can help with displaying the values 1-12 as Jan-Dec? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not `.Value = DateSerial(2016, 5, 1)` ?

Comment: @Jeeped because this way a date will be written into the cell. But I want to write only an integer into the cell

Comment: You could have a worksheet_change event to use Jeeped's suggestion and change the value when someone types it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is mission critical that you bypass the rules of dates and numbers then write 12 conditional formatting rules; one for each number/month name from 1 to 12 and supply a 'literal' custom format mask for each that spells out the abbreviated month.

```
Sub cf_months()
    Dim m As Long, cnf As String
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A1")
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            For m = 12 To 1 Step -1
                cnf = StrConv(Format(DateSerial(2016, m, 1), "mmm"), vbUnicode)
                cnf = Join(Split(cnf, vbNullChar), Chr(92))
                cnf = Chr(91) & Chr(61) & m & Chr(93) & Chr(92) & Left(cnf, Len(cnf) - 1) & Chr(59) & Chr(59) & Chr(59)
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=Chr(61) & .Address(0, 0) & Chr(61) & m
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).NumberFormat = cnf
                Debug.Print cnf
            Next m
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: cf_months]

Comment: does it matter if the for loop was 1 to 12 instead of 12 to 1 step -1?

Comment: If you record yourself creating a CF rule, you'll find that they are always created at the bottom of the queue and then reordered so that the new one is at the top. I didn't reorder and typically chop the code down to what is necessary. I think I overthought the process and reversed the order in order to maintain a Jan-Dec queue when in fact I created a Dec-Jan queue in the CF manager. Since there is no overlap of the conditions, it shouldn't matter.