# Exponential number in custom number format of Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, number-formatting

In an Excel chart, I have some values on the x-axis: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
But these values are actually in logarithm. Therefore, I need to show the exponential numbers as the labels of x-axis like: 10, 100, 1000, 10000, and 100000.

I tried the 'Format Axis' --> 'Number' --> 'Custom' in order to add a new format code to support that. But it didn't work.

The best thing I've got so far is

```
10^#,##0;10^#,##0
```

But it just gives me exactly 10^x which is not what I need.

Any idea?

Comment: Why not basic Excel scientific notation number format?

Comment: Or can't you just create the numbers you want to see in a separate column and source this column as your Xs?

Comment: I tried the scientific notation, it didn't work either.
Sth like 1.0E+#;1.0E+# you mean?

Comment: @zaptask, well, basically I needed a pyramid shape chart, but in logarithmic scale, and as negative numbers cannot be 'logarithmed', I had to first take the logarithm and then make them negative. That's the reason.

Comment: See the solution I provided earlier in [Show name of month according to a number in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416971/show-name-of-month-according-to-a-number-in-excel/36417417#36417417). Change the month names to your exponentials.

Comment: @Jeeped I'm not sure if I got your idea. I need to show it on the chart, just as the labels of x-axis.